# not getting result while running jquery script in python selenium getting blank values

Tags: python, selenium

I want run query in python script my code is as below, 
`driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('billToPartyNumber_t')")`

but this gives me Blank values  selected query is like as below,

```
data-bind="attr: {id: fieldId(),maxlength: maxLen},
 event: {change: change.bind($data),
focus: handleFocus.bind($data),blur: handleBlur.bind($data)},
        ojComponent: ojOptions.extend({component: 'ojInputText'})"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"billToPartyNumber_t"))).get_attribute('innerHTML)
print(elem)
```

By using get_attribute('innerHTML') you may check if the element is present with its values, then by getting the text for example, use like `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "billToPartyNumber_t"))).text`